# Green to python, having issues with Discord Embed

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So keep getting a Type error stating send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Embed'
I'm not sure what I did wrong. Any help would be awesome.

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'what is the version':
        dev_channel = client.get_channel(Deleted for obs reasons)

        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Current Version", description="The bot 
        is in Version 1.0", color=0x00ff00)
        
        myEmbed.add_field(name="Version Code:", value="v1.0.0", inline=False)
        
        myEmbed.add_field(name="Date Released:", value="November 25th, 2020", 
        inline=False)

        myEmbed.set_footer(text="End of message")

        await dev_channel.send(Embed=myEmbed)
```

Visual Studios gives following text in terminal when I type what is the version in the discord text channel.

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                               
", line 333, in _run_event
File "C:\Users\lazy5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\discord\client.pyy", line 333, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users\lazy5\Desktop\worth.py", line 30, in on_message
await dev_channel.send(Embed=myEmbed)
TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Embed'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your send line

```
await dev_channel.send(Embed=myEmbed)
```

'*Embed=*' should be lowercase like so:

```
await dev_channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

Comment: I've changed that aswell, no change. I feel as if its not picking up the embed module from discord.

Comment: @RWT98 I've tested your code with the fix. Can you send your revised code over please?

Comment: So I've tried a fair bit of stuff to try and figure it out on my own, but no luck here is a screenshot of the error I get. The bot comes online and will stay online till I type in the chat "what is the version". I'm starting to think something is not installed correctly? https://imgur.com/a/ettcTUH Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: @RWT98 The answer is still correct. You changed the code. capitalize the 'e' on embed in line 11 and run it again.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I ended up finding that was the issue, but shortly after started to have more problems with importing panda. I ended up switching from 3.9 to 3.8 and it's been smooth sailing since. Once again thanks for taking the time to help!